# How to generate URL from within actor in Play Framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I have an actor, called NotificationActor, that runs every 10 minutes and sends the latest notifications out via email.  these emails contain links back to the app to the specific resource the notification is notifying on.  The problem is I dont have access to a **request** object from within my actor (at least not that I know of...) in order to generate the absolute URL's back to the app like so:

```
val url = routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL(request())
```

Here is my actor for reference:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.event.Logging
import play.api.{Play, Mode, DefaultApplication, Application}
import java.io.File
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import models.Notification.Action
import com.feth.play.module.mail.Mailer
import com.feth.play.module.mail.Mailer.Mail
import com.feth.play.module.mail.Mailer.Mail.Body

class NotificationActor extends Actor {
    val log = Logging(context.system, this)
    def receive = {
        case "runNotificationJob" ⇒ {

            val notifications = <get List of new notifications>

            for (notification <- notifications) {
                notifyByEmail(notification)
            }
        }
        case _      ⇒ log.info("received unknown message")
    }

    def notifyByEmail(notification: Notification) {
        val subject:String = s"PostSubject"


        val url:String = routes.MyController.myMethod(notification.post, notification.action).absoluteURL(request()) // Broken because there is no request() here

        val body = new Body(s"Message Body with url $url")

        val mail = new Mail(subject, body, Array(notificationStatus.getRecipient.getEmail))
        mailer.sendMail(mail)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call only looks at the hostname from the `RequestHeader` so you could create a fake just providing the hostname, the problem is that the play server does not really care what hostname it is served from, it might even be more than one etc, so you would still have to hardcode or put the hostname you want to in your config file.

(Since your example route does not take parameters the url will not change during the life of the actor, so you probably don't need to create the url each time you send a mail though.)

So you could do something like:

```
lazy val publicUrl: String = { 
   val publicHostname = ???
   routes.MyController.myMethod().absoluteURL(secure = false)(new RequestHeader(){
     override lazy val host = publicHostname
     def remoteAddress = ???
     def headers = ???
     def queryString = ???
     def version = ???
     def method = ???
     def path = ???
     def uri = ???
     def tags = ???
     def id = ???
   })
}
```

Comment: The route **does** take parameters (I went ahead and updated my example to reflect that) so I would need to generate a new url each time.  Your solution worked great for this use case!

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in your conf, and have a different configuration for each server it is deployed on.  Not super elegant, but that is how I solved it.